# SQL Server 2000 command to disable user account

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to disable some user accounts within a sql server version 2000. the following sql command is giving me an " incorrect syntax near 'Login' " error. The user name is valid and spelled correctly so I'm wondering if the command syntax is different for version 2000.

```
ALTER LOGIN exampleuser DISABLE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 doesn't have the ALTER LOGIN statement. So to be able to disable the login you'll have to call the sp_denylogin procedure instead.

```
EXEC sp_denylogin 'exampleuser'
```

or

```
EXEC sp_revokelogin 'exampleuser'
```

To give them back access again you should use

```
EXEC sp_grantlogin 'exampleuser'
```

*Note:* `sp_denylogin`, `sp_revokelogin` and `sp_grantlogin` only works on Windows accounts and groups.

To be able to deny pure SQL Server logins, it seems like the only option is to remove that login completely with

```
EXEC sp_droplogin 'exampleuser'
```

but to enable it again, it needs to be re-created with

```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'exampleuser', 'examplepassword'
```

or just remove that logins access to the **current** database with

```
EXEC sp_revokedbaccess 'exampleuser'
```

Comment: Do you know what the command is to enable the account after it's been disabled?

Comment: Is this method only valid for Windows NT user or groups?

Comment: To be honest. I'm not entirely sure. They should apply to both SQL Server logins and Windows NT users.

Comment: This command fails when i try to use it on a non winders nt user :( 
msg: windows nt user or group 'exampleuser' not found. check the name again.

Comment: hmm, ok, that I didn't know. Then I think the only option you can do is use the sp_droplogin procedure and remove the user login completely

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove the user from each of the databases with sp_revokedbaccess. That will stop them from entering any databases, even if they still can access the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

sp_revokelogin will remove the login entry. However , this proc has been [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188784.aspx)
in favour of [drop login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188012.aspx)

But note that both of these will not disable the user but *delete* the login.

Your ALTER LOGIN approach is correct

```
ALTER LOGIN exampleuser DISABLE;
```

works with sql server 2008 atleast.

Comment: In SQL Server 2000 it is not deprecated, instead the only way to do it. CREATE LOGIN, ALTER LOGIN and DROP LOGIN was introduced in 2005